# not getting data from JSON file using angularjs 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to get data from my JSON file using AngularJs 1.6

```
  myApp.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.Data = [];
      var getJsonData = function() {
          $http.get('contactlist.json').then(function(response) {
              $scope.Data = response.data;
              console.log(response.data);
          });
      }
      getJsonData();
  });
```

But it's not going to response I am putting debug on then line but my page opened without stopping on debug response. So it's not going on then(function(reponse){

My JSON File:

```
var contactList = [
{
"firstName": "Joe",
"lastName": "Perry",
"contactNumber": "444-888-1223",
"contactEmail": "joe@cordis.us"
},
{
"firstName": "Kate",
"lastName": "Will",
"contactNumber": "244-838-1213",
"contactEmail": "kate@cordis.us"
}
];
```

Comment: what is the log of console.log(response) ?

Comment: it's not getting triggered

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: i am getting error:

Comment: what error please explain?

Comment: angular.js:14525 Error: [$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "var contactList = [
{
"firstName": "Joe",
"lastName": "Perry",
"contactNumber": "444-888-1223",
"contactEmail": "joe@cordis.us"
},
{
...
}
];". Parse error: "{}"
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?p0=var%20contactList%20%3D%…0A%22contactEmail%22%3A%20%22roger%40cordis.us%22%0A%7D%0A%5D%3B&p1=%7B%7D
    at angular.js:66
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:11177)
    at angular.js:11270
    at forEach (angular.js:403)
    at transformData (angular.js:11269)

Comment: Your JSON file really starts with "var"? Then it's not valid JSON.

Comment: I tried removing var then also same error

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved. Issue was because of semicolon at the end of json file data.
Got this error when tried pasting in Plunker editor
My Bad.

Comment: see in my answer I have removed that too, and provided you a workable JSON... :)

Comment: if you feel that really helps then mark it as accepted in order to help others (including me :P )

Comment: i did since i am a new user it wont be counted

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var contactList =` from you `JSON` file and place the JSON contents only

like:

```
[
   {
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Perry",
        "contactNumber": "444-888-1223",
        "contactEmail": "joe@cordis.us"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kate",
        "lastName": "Will",
        "contactNumber": "244-838-1213",
        "contactEmail": "kate@cordis.us"
    }
]
```

`var contactList = <something>` meant it's javascript code need to be execute, but you are reading the file and parsing it as a json data and not executing as `js` file, so make it like a json file so the contents is only json string and not some javascript code.

Comment: what was the exact failure message/log in this case?

Comment: Error: [$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "[{"id":1}". Parse error: "{}"
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?p0=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%7D&p1=%7B%7D
    at angular.js:66
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:11177)
    at angular.js:11270
    at forEach (angular.js:403)
    at transformData (angular.js:11269)
    at transformResponse (angular.js:12090)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16832)
    at angular.js:16876
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17971)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18269) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Comment: i tried this for only {"id":1} in a new test.json but still the same error

Comment: then wrap it in a object

Comment: and are you sure that you putting the path correctly? what's the network tab says in the devTools/firebug?

Comment: @kaushik  I am giving the path correctly there is no error in network tab

Comment: If you see the error  [$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "[{"id":1}".   {"id":1} is the value which i wrote in test.json file

Comment: can you share a plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Change your json file to(your json is not valid):

```
[{"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Perry","contactNumber":"444-888-1223","contactEmail":"joe@cordis.us"},{"firstName":"Kate","lastName":"Will","contactNumber":"244-838-1213","contactEmail":"kate@cordis.us"}]
```